# Php5-client not running

Tags: php, mysql, bash, symfony-1.4

Hello people I have been stuck with a problem that plagued me for like 2 weeks and I don't know why. First I tought it was the symfony project I cloned from my partners repository but it has something to do with the php service I'm running it on. The console log shows this error:

```
[Tue Nov  1 15:16:57 2016] 127.0.0.1:7471 [200]: /frontend_dev.php
```

Besides that it says that it contains a lot of syntax errors.

I tried running the server on port 80 and It worked once. When I shut down te computer It says that another application is running on the port. Which makes sence,b but I would like to know why it worked once on port 80 and how to fix this problem because I was also looking around on the internet for answers, but nothing worked.

**My enviroment:**

- *Windows 10 with the ubuntu bash shell.*
- *Symfony 1.4.20 propel*
- *php 5.5.9*
- *mysql 5.5.53*

**Installed packages:**

- *Php5-cli*
- *php5-common*
- *php5-json*
- *php5-mysql*
- *php5-readline*
- *php5-xsl*
- *mysql-client*
- *mysql-client-5.5*
- *mysql-client-core-5.5*
- *mysql-common*
- *mysql-server*
- *mysql-server-5.5*
- *mysql-server-core-5.5*

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc:**

```
 127.0.0.1         localhost
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 MY-PC-NAME

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I hope someone knows what could be wrong here.

Comment: Did you try to find out which process is listening on port 80? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/4681654)

Comment: @simon Thank you for sharing this. I tried killing the php5 proces running in the background on port 80 and now it works. There is only one problem. I'm using the command: "php -S localhost:80 -t web" but it doesn't seem to work on port 8000 which is the default port.

Comment: If you want to run PHP on port 8000 you need to use `php -S localhost:8000 -t web`. The documentation has more information about the [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this version of Symfony will run on the PHP version you have installed. That could be your first problem.

To check this download the configuration checker at

```
http://sf-to.org/1.4/check.php
```

and put in in your project root folder then run:

```
php check_configuration.php
```

For the port problem try to figure out which process might be using it.

Also consider using a newer version of Symfony for a new project.

Comment: But for this project I need to work  with symfony 1.4 because it's developed in symfony 1.4.20